# Alternatives to WebHCat

Tags: hadoop, hive, webhdfs

Hive has an option of using WebHCat for querying HIVE Tables via REST based API's.

WebHCat requires 2 calls -

- Call 1 to submit the query via webhcat.
- Call 2 to retrieve the output file via webhdfs.

Are there any other alternatives to webhcat that allows applications to make REST based calls to HIVE Database without requiring Java/Python/.NET etc?

Thanks,
Manish